# Mongoose using subquery in aggregation to sum data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new in mongoose. I have model like this.

```
var ForumSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
User_id             : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User'},
Title               : {type : String},
Content             : {type : String},
Tags                : [{type : String}],
isPublic            : {type : Boolean, default : false},
Vote                : [{
    User_id         : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User'},
    Kind            : {type : Boolean}
}],
Rate                : [{
    User_id         : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User'},
    Count           : {type : Number}
}],
Comment             : [{
    User_id         : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User'},
    Content         : String,
    Created_at      : {type : Date, required : true, default : Date.now}
}],
Created_at          : {type : Date, required : true, default : Date.now},
Updated_at          : {type : Date}
```

});

I want to get Forum data with sum of `Vote` that value is true. Like this json.

```
{
[
    _id         : <Some object id>,
    User_id     : <Some object id from User Model>,
    Title       : <Title>,
    Content     : <Content>,
    Tags        : [Some array],
    isPublic    : true,
    UpVote      : 23,
    ....
    ....
    ....
]
```

}

In mysql I can do this by using subquery. How can I do it in mongoose?

Comment: Let us know what you have tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With MongoDB server 3.4 and above, you can run an aggregate pipeline that uses the **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** operator which has a **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** on the `Vote` array to filter those element that have a `Kind` property value matching true and when you get the filtered array, use it as an input expression for the **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operator which then calculates the count of the items in the filtered array.

Consider the following operation to get the desired result:

```
Forum.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "UpVote": {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$Vote",
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": "$$el.Kind"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).exec((err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
})
```

---

### Explanations

In the above, the inner expression

```
{
    "$filter": {
        "input": "$Vote",
        "as": "el",
        "cond": "$$el.Kind"
    }
}
```

selects a subset of the array to return based on the specified condition. As a result, it returns an array with only those elements that match the condition.

The **`input`** property refers to an expression that resolves to an array. In the above, the input is the Votes array.

The other field **`as`** represents the variable name for the element in the input array. The **`as`** expression accesses each element in the input array by this variable.

The **`cond`** field holds an expression that determines whether to include the element in the resulting array. The expression accesses the element by the variable name specified in **`as`**.

So in the above if the element in the array being evaluated has the `Kind` subproperty equal to `true`, denoted by the expression `"$$el.Kind"`, then the condition is matched and the element is included in the subset to be returned.

As a simple example, take for instance this high-level expression:

```
{
    "$filter": {
        "input": [
            { "Kind": true, "User_id": "58afed97bc343887a9ac9206" },
            { "Kind": false, "User_id": "58ad50a429b2961777f91c97" },
            { "Kind": true, "User_id": "58b3f0f598501abacd8ff391" }
        ],
        "as": "el",
        "cond": {
            "$eq": ["$$el.Kind", true]
        }
    }
}
```

returns the array

```
[
    { "Kind": true, "User_id": "58afed97bc343887a9ac9206" },
    { "Kind": true, "User_id": "58b3f0f598501abacd8ff391" }
]
```

The conditional part

```
"cond": {
    "$eq": ["$$el.Kind", true]
}
```

can be simplified to just

```
"cond": "$$el.Kind"
```

as `"$$el.Kind"` expression already evaluates to a boolean.

The **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operator trivially calculates the number of elements in an array, thus the expression, for example

```
{
    "$size":    {
        "$filter": {
            "input": [
                { "Kind": true, "User_id": "58afed97bc343887a9ac9206" },
                { "Kind": false, "User_id": "58ad50a429b2961777f91c97" },
                { "Kind": true, "User_id": "58b3f0f598501abacd8ff391" }
            ],
            "as": "el",
            "cond": {
                "$eq": ["$$el.Kind", true]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is expressed as

```
{
    "$size": [
        { "Kind": true, "User_id": "58afed97bc343887a9ac9206" },
        { "Kind": true, "User_id": "58b3f0f598501abacd8ff391" }
    ]
}
```

and return a result with 2 as count.

For the contrary DownVote count, the same logic applies:

```
Forum.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "UpVote": {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$Vote",
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": "$$el.Kind"
                    }
                }
            },
            "DownVote": {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$Vote",
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": { "$not": ["$$el.Kind"] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).exec((err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
})
```

---

For the earlier MongoDB version 3.2, you will need to project each and every other element in the document:

```
Forum.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "User_id"     : 1,
            "Title"       : 1,
            "Content"     : 1,
            "Tags"        : 1,
            "isPublic"    : 1,
            "UpVote"      : {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$Vote",
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": "$$el.Kind"
                    }
                }
            },
            ....
            ....
            ....
        }
    }
]).exec((err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
})
```

---

For versions that do not support the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator, use the **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operator instead as:

```
Forum.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "User_id"     : 1,
            "Title"       : 1,
            "Content"     : 1,
            "Tags"        : 1,
            "isPublic"    : 1,
            "UpVote"      : {
                "$size": {
                    "$setDifference": [
                        { "$map": {
                            "input": "$Vote",
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": { "$cond": ["$$el.Kind", "$$el", false] }               
                        }},
                        [false]
                    ]
                }
            },
            ....
            ....
            ....
        }
    }
]).exec((err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
})
```

Comment: THis is work I think. But what this mean? 
`"as": "el",
                        "cond": "$$el.Kind"`

Comment: I've added some bits of explanation on what's going on behind the scenes but for more detail, consult the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).

Comment: Thank, this is works. I just run it like this `"$filter": {
                         "input": "$Vote",
                         "as": "vote",
                         "cond": {
                          "$eq": [ "$$vote.Kind", true ]
                      }
                     }`

Comment: Awesome, it may be syntactic sugar but the expression `"$filter": { "input": "$Vote", "as": "vote", "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$vote.Kind", true ] } }` can be simplified to just `"$filter": { "input": "$Vote", "as": "vote", "cond": "$$vote.Kind" }` as `"$$vote.Kind"` expression already evaluates to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

you can use aggregate in mongodb

```
db.getCollection('forum').aggregate([{
        $unwind: "$Vote"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "Vote. Kind": true
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            "User_id": {
                '$first': '$User_id'
            },
            "Title": {
                '$first': '$Title'
            },
            UpVote: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

you can use this same query in mongoose also, finally you get number of up votes

Comment: Is this possible if I want to show `DownVote` with this?